# Backbone.js Push state and page state after reload using Symfony

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, symfony

ive got a question. Im using backbone.js with push state and navigate to push url and execute actions. Im using symfony2 for backend. Now the question is how to handle the routes e.g. /reviews that are loaded via symfony routing, not backone. Is there any was to avoid code duplication?

Answer (score 0):

If you only target is javascript-enabled clients, don't do anything on those routes - just show the same page for all the requests received by symphony.

If you want to support clients without javascript too, try to reuse your templates. You can use the underscore templates http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/docs/underscore.html#section-120 (just change the delimiters to use {{ and {* and use Twig in symphony). Then, you should make sure you send the same data to the template from symphony and from Backbone. Basically, when you render a template, you send data in the same format as you do on the server.

```
var PostView = Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function() {
    $(this.el).html(this.template({post: this.model.toJSON()}));
    // so you can use post.title post.description in the template
  }
})
```